# Only retrieve YYYY-MM-DD from moment

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

Doing `moment().format()` returns `2018-05-30T11:38:04+10:00`.

How can I retrieve only the `2018-05-30` part of it?

Comment: Why not just substring from 0 to the location of T-1?

Comment: it's a very clunky solution imo

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty this is not recommended solution which provided by Freddy. Checkout my answer for right solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go. You need to pass format string in `moment().format("you desired date/time format in string format")` function

```js
let date = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```

For more information, checkout this link for formatting :

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)('T')

```
var date = "2018-05-30T11:38:04+10:00";
date = date.split('T')[0];

console.log(date)
// expected output: "2018-05-30"
```